# Accept and Decline button is not working in mail

Tags: php

I am sending a mail after user submits form to approve are disapprove the data through link in mail. Here is the code:

```
$subject = 'User needs approval';
$message = 'The user $empname needs your approval' .
'----------------------------------- ' . "\r\n" .
'Accept: ' . $accept_link . "\r\n" .
'Decline: ' . $decline_link . "\r\n";

$_headers = 'From:admin@yourwebsite.com' . "\r\n"; // Set FROM headers
//mail($supemail, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send the email
fnMail($supemail,"mailb@mail.com"," Web master","reimbursement Form",$message);
```

The link to accept and decline is:

```
$accept_link = "http://communique/elegant-contact-form/quick-contact/ajax/approval.php?e=" . $empemail . "&h=" . hash('sha512', 'ACCEPT');

$decline_link = "http://communique/elegant-contact-form/quick-contact/ajax/approval.php?e="  . $empemail . "&h=" . hash('sha512', 'DECLINE');
```

and here is the approval.php file:

```
$hash = $_GET['h'];
$email = $_GET['e'];
if($hash == hash('sha512', 'ACCEPT')){
$res=execQuery('oth','update form set approved=1 where empemail="$email"');

if(count($res)>0){
   fnMail($email,"mk.web@mattsenkumar.com","MattsenKumar Web master","Contact Front registration",'APPROVED');
}
}else if($hash == hash('sha512', 'DECLINE')){

fnMail($email,"mk.web@mattsenkumar.com","MattsenKumar Web master","Contact Front registration",'DECLINE');
}
```

But I got the mail like this:

```
The user $empname needs your approval----------------------------------- Accept: Decline:
```

Comment: This looks like it should work OK. Can you provide the actual code that includes the definition of `$accept_link` as well as `$message`? `$empname` is not being interpreted because it is inside single quotes, you should replace `'` with `"` or use `'The user ' . $empname . ' needs your approval'`. To ensure the user followed the link you sent them your hash should include their email address and a known secret. If you're just hashing `ACCEPT` and `DECLINE` you might as well just write `ACCEPT` and `DECLINE`. You are defining `$_headers` but not using it anywhere. Where is `fnMail()` defined?

Comment: To make it work use html in your mail, it will help you to trigger the link. Use Anchor link, rather using row text

Comment: **JiteshNK** can you help me with that

Comment: Something like this `$message = "<div style='float:left'>The user $empname needs your approval</div>";
$messsge .= "<div><a href='your accept link here'>Accept</a><a href="your decline link here">decline</a></div>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is day-1 basic PHP syntax: variables are not interpolated into single-quoted strings. [Read the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), do this:

```
$message = "The user $empname needs your approval" .
```

For the accept and deny links to be included in the message you must define them *before* you use them, like this:

```
$accept_link = "http://communique/elegant-contact-form/quick-contact/ajax/approval.php?e=" . $empemail . "&h=" . hash('sha512', 'ACCEPT');
$decline_link = "http://communique/elegant-contact-form/quick-contact/ajax/approval.php?e="  . $empemail . "&h=" . hash('sha512', 'DECLINE');
$message = "The user $empname needs your approval" .
'----------------------------------- ' . "\r\n" .
'Accept: ' . $accept_link . "\r\n" .
'Decline: ' . $decline_link . "\r\n";
```

Comment: thanks for the $empname but i am asking about $accept_link and decline link
i receive the mail like this
**The user $empname needs your approval----------------------------------- Accept: Decline:**

but here accept and decline is not clickable means there is no link with them.

Comment: I am receiving mail **fnMail()** is working fine its defined in mailfunction.php file

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question, but it looks like you define the link variables *after* you build the body string, so it will not contain them.

Comment: thanks bro i have edited approval.php file to something like this :-
`if($hash == hash('sha512', 'ACCEPT')){
 $qry="update form set approved='1' where empemail='$email';";
$res=execQuery("oth",$qry);
if(count($res)>0)
{
 echo 'Approved';
 fnMail($email,"mk.web@mattsenkumar.com","MattsenKumar Web master","Contact Front registration",'APPROVED');
}`

**and its works perfectly**
again thanks for your help

Comment: Make sure you sanitise/escape `$email` to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score -2):

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
```

Try setting the headers

or check this below stackoverflow link

hope this will help

[PHP mail() - How to put an html link in an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711700/php-mail-how-to-put-an-html-link-in-an-email)

Comment: This is not an answer to this question, it's nothing to do with headers.